# How to define retrofit MultipartBody.Part Part Name in API Interfacce

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, multipart, retrofit2.6

How can I define `MultipartBody.Part` Part Name in the API Interface.

So I want to define `@Part image: MultipartBody.Part`

To be like `@Part("image") image: MultipartBody.Part`

So I want some way that I can omit `"image"` from `MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", image.name, requestBody)`

But `@Part("image")` do not work with `MulitipartBody.Part`

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("someEndPoint")
    suspend fun uploadSometing(

        @Header("Authorization") token: String,

        @Part image: MultipartBody.Part

        ): Response
```

```
val requestBody = image.asRequestBody()

val imagePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", image.name, requestBody)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this ?

```
@Multipart
@POST("someEndPoint")
suspend fun uploadSometing(

    @Header("Authorization") token: String,

    @Part image: MultipartBody.Part

    ): Response

//code in your API services
fun editProfile(photo: File?) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val imageBody = photo?.let { 
                compressImage(it).toRequestBody("image") }
            val response = services.editImage(
                photo = imageBody
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

so you define the **"image"** part name in the API interface